# Customizing Modals with angular-modal-service (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm using ([`angular-modal-service`](https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service)) to create popups and modals via a service but I would like to know how it is possible to customize them? For instance, how can I change the `modal-header` color or remove the "by default" lines between the header, body and footer? Thank you.

**Sample of the controllers:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['angularModalService']);

app.controller('Controller', function($scope, ModalService) {

$scope.show = function() {
    ModalService.showModal({
        templateUrl: 'modal.html',
        controller: "ModalController"
    }).then(function(modal) {
        modal.element.modal();
        modal.close.then(function(result) {
            $scope.message = "You said " + result;
        });
    });
 };

});

app.controller('ModalController', function($scope, close) {

$scope.close = function(result) {
   close(result, 500); // close, but give 500ms for bootstrap to animate
};

});
```

**Sample of the html:**

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service/master/dst/angular-modal-service.js"></script>

<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller">

    <h3>Angular Modal Service</h3>
     <a class="btn btn-default" href ng-click="show()">Show a Modal</a>
     <p>{{message}}</p>

     <!-- The actual modal template, just a bit o bootstrap -->
     <script type="text/ng-template" id="modal.html">
         <div class="modal fade">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="close('Cancel')" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Yes or No?</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p>It's your call...</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" ng-click="close('No')" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                <button type="button" ng-click="close('Yes')" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </script>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a CSS question.

To change modal colors or borders you have to add a custom CSS.

You can play with google dev tool to change styles and see the results in real-time so you don't have to reload the page.

**To change header color:**

```
.modal-header {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**To hide border in footer:**

```
.modal-footer {
    border-top: 0px!important;
}
```

Comment: Definitely easiest than I thought. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use css for that otherwise convert it into custom directive